# connecting dots in 2 different data sets in R

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, line

I have 2 data sets (DSA and DSB) that contain x & y coordinates

```
tumor<- data.frame(DSA[,c("X_Parameter","Y_Parameter")])
cells<-data.frame(DSB[,c ("X_Parameter","Y_Parameter")])
plot(cells, xlim=c(1,1300), ylim=c(1,1000), col="red")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(tumor, xlim=c(1,1300), ylim=c(1,1000), col="blue")
```

the plots make this graph
[image]

I want to be able to draw a connecting line from every red dot to every blue dot.
Does anyone know if this can be done.  thanks

Sample 
DSA=(5,5 6,6 5,6 6,5) DSB=(1,1 10,10 10,1 1,10)
what the plot should look like[image]

Comment: Are you intending to create 1000s of lines here? This can be brute-forced, but perhaps you should look at [`igraph`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html).

Comment: @tluh you are correct.  At the end there would be number of red dots) * (number of blue dots) lines. Sample data sets are listed in x,y pairs. DSA=(5,5  6,6  5,6  6,5) DSB=(1,1  10,10  10,1  1,10). see attached picture of what it should look like below

Comment: There is a `outer` function that would let you construct the set of two-way combinations and then use `segments`. You are responsible for offering a data example if you want tested code. Your data example doesn't make sense because it does not have two coordinates for each point.

Comment: @42 sorry I should have made the data sets more clear. In the sample set 5,5 is point 1 with 5=X1,5=Y1 the 6,6 is then the second point 6=X2,6=Y2 and so on, I hope that is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute-force, perhaps inelegant:

```
DSA <- data.frame(x = c(5, 6, 5, 6),
                  y = c(5, 6, 6, 5))
DSB <- data.frame(x = c(1, 10, 10, 1),
                  y = c(1, 10, 1, 10))

plot(y ~ x, DSB, col = "red")
points(DSA, col = "blue")
for (r in seq_len(nrow(DSA))) {
  segments(DSA$x[r], DSA$y[r], DSB$x, DSB$y)
}
```

[image: brute force segments]

Edit: more directly:

```
nA <- nrow(DSA)
nB <- nrow(DSB)
plot(y ~ x, DSB, col = "red")
points(DSA, col = "blue")
segments(rep(DSA$x, each = nB),  rep(DSA$y, each = nB),
         rep(DSB$x, times = nA), rep(DSB$y, times = nA))
```

(I still can't figure out an elegant solution with @42's recommendation for `combn` or `outer`.)